# Extracting values from list of list in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list as follows:

```
mylist = [
    ['OF', 'O'],
    ['ODH', 'O'],
    ['1937066911', 'NUMBER'],
    ['FLOYD', 'PERSON'],
    ['WESLEY', 'PERSON'],
    ['MCGRAW', 'PERSON'],
    ['04', 'NUMBER'],
    ['RUTH', 'PERSON'],
    ['MAE', 'PERSON'],
    ['MCGRAW', 'PERSON']
]
```

This is the desired output

```
desired_output = [
    {'O':'OF', 'ODH'},
    {'NUMBER':'1937066911'},
    {'PERSON':'FLOYD','WESLEY','MCGRAW'},
    {'NUMBER':'04'},
    {'PERSON':'RUTH','MAE','MCGRAW'}
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
new_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('A.json') as jsonfile:
    file_data = json.load(jsonfile)
    for d in range(len(file_data)):
       try:
          if file_data[d][1] in file_data[d+1]:
            new_dict[file_data[d][1]].append(file_data[0])
       except:
             pass
    print(new_dict)
```

NOTE A.json has the list of list as shown above

Comment: This output is not possible. What datastructure is `{'O':'OF', 'ODH',}` supposed to be?

Comment: probably `{'O':('OF', 'ODH')}`

Comment: What i meant is list of dictionaries with one key holding multiple values

Comment: Why having a list of dictionaries with only 1 key per dict when you can have 1 dictionary with multiple keys?

Comment: yes Chris_Rands you are right either like that or like {'O':['OF', 'ODH']}, sorry for my mistake

Comment: in your output you have a list of dictionaries, but some of those dictionaries contain the same keys (e.g `number` and `person`). are they meant to be separate dicts? and if so what criteria are you using to separate them?

Comment: Yes I want them to be separate keys the reason is let us think about person key, I have multiple person name now if this is the case i will get all the names under person key which i do not want.

Comment: regarding the logic i have is the to iterate through the list get the adjacent key now if they are same i will add them to a dictionary and append in a list the move to next but this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), assuming you want a list of dicts where the values are list:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

lst = [['OF', 'O'], ['ODH', 'O'], ['1937066911', 'NUMBER'], ['FLOYD', 'PERSON'], ['WESLEY', 'PERSON'],
          ['MCGRAW', 'PERSON'], ['04', 'NUMBER'], ['RUTH', 'PERSON'], ['MAE', 'PERSON'], ['MCGRAW', 'PERSON']]

result = [{ k : list(map(itemgetter(0), group))} for k, group in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(1))]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'O': ['OF', 'ODH']}, {'NUMBER': ['1937066911']}, {'PERSON': ['FLOYD', 'WESLEY', 'MCGRAW']}, {'NUMBER': ['04']}, {'PERSON': ['RUTH', 'MAE', 'MCGRAW']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best we can do here is a list of dicts with lists as values.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [['OF', 'O'],['ODH', 'O'],['1937066911', 'NUMBER'],['FLOYD', 'PERSON'],['WESLEY', 'PERSON'],['MCGRAW', 'PERSON'],['04', 'NUMBER'],['RUTH', 'PERSON'],['MAE', 'PERSON'],['MCGRAW', 'PERSON']]
first = itemgetter(0)
second = itemgetter(1)
result = []

for key, group in groupby(mylist, key=second):
    result.append({key:[first(g) for g in group]})
```

result:

```
>>> result
[{'O': ['OF', 'ODH']},
 {'NUMBER': ['1937066911']},
 {'PERSON': ['FLOYD', 'WESLEY', 'MCGRAW']},
 {'NUMBER': ['04']},
 {'PERSON': ['RUTH', 'MAE', 'MCGRAW']}]
```